# Describing a linear predictor for a stationary process with a set of equations

Tags: statistics, time-series, stationary-processes

In some exam review I received the following question

> 2. Assume that $\{X_{t}\}$ is a stationary time series, with mean $\mu$ and acvf $\gamma(h)$. Let $P_{n}X_{n+h}$ be the optimal (in terms of MSE) linear prediction of $X_{n+h}$ based on $X_{1},...,X_{n}$. Show explicitly how to write down a set of equations which define $P_{n}X_{n+h}$ in the case $n=2$ and $h=1$.

Now I know that the best linear predictor of $X_{n+h}$ given the set $X_{n}, \text{...} , X_{1}$ is 
\begin{equation*}Pred(X_{n+h}|X_{n}, \text{...}, X_{1}) = \mu + (a_{1}, \text{...}, a_{n})^{T}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{n}-\mu \\
X_{n-1}-\mu \\
. \\
. \\
X_{1} - \mu
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{a}$ satisfies the avcf equation. I also know the MSE is given by $$\gamma(0) - \mathbf{a}^{T}\gamma(n,h)$$.

What I'm unsure about is what exactly a set of equations defining my optimal predictor would look like. Do I simply plug in $n=2$ and $h=1$ to rewrite the definition I've given, or is there something more to it?